# Inorder on a BinTree type script

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was given a task to implement a function that iterate over a bin tree and return an array of all its value in inorder. The code is as below:

```
interface BinTree {
root: number;
left?: BinTree;
right?: BinTree;
 };
 const TreeInArray =(t:BinTree):number[] =>{
       let list = new Array<number>(); 
        if (t.left!=undefined) { 
            list = list.concat(TreePreArray(t.left))  
        }
       list.push(t.root)
       if (t.right!=undefined) { 
          list = list.concat(TreePreArray(t.right))
        }
    return list
 }
 let bn1 : BinTree = { // DOES NOT PASS TYPE CHECKING
 root: 1,
 left: { root: 2 ,
    left:{root:4 },right:{root:5 } },
 right: { root: 3}
 }
 console.log((TreeInArray(bn1)));
```

The output is

```
[ 2, 4, 5, 1, 3 ]
```

I expected output similar to this

```
[4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the pre-order version instead of the in-order version recursively:

```
const TreeInArray = (t: BinTree): number[] => {
    let list = new Array<number>();
    if (t.left != undefined) {
        list = list.concat(TreeInArray(t.left))
    }
    list.push(t.root)
    if (t.right != undefined) {
        list = list.concat(TreeInArray(t.right))
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: sorry please remove this question it is not helpful